# How to search a phrase in PDF using ContentDocument in Salesforce Apex?

Tags: salesforce, jspdf, apex

My requirement is to search a Phrase in PDF in ContentDocument.
Can anyone please help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried https://pdf.co/parse-invoice-using-salesforce-apex-using-pdfco and https://www.congruentsoft.com/blog/salesforce/extract-text-from-pdf-files.aspx
But I want this automation in Apex and I want to check 500 Preloaded PDF.
So how can we achieve this?